# How to keep Mac alive while connected to a VPN

Tags: network, vpn

I use Mac OS native VPN client to remotely connect to the database server at the office but I find annoying that VPN connection drops when the computer is idle for a while.

In order to avoid that I use the Amphetamine app and I found that the time awaken can be  defined as "while a certain app or process is running".

I guess the VPN client runs as a process but I am unable to locate it in the list of running processes offered by Amphetamine, do you know if it's there and its name?

Maybe you know of a better solution to keep the native Mac OS VPN alive, if so, don't forget to mention it in your reply.

Comment: You need to enable the `keepalive` option.  Are you using OpenVPN?

Comment: I'm using L2TP, and I don't know how to use the *keepalive* option